# Wrong solution of $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\ln x}{\tanh ^{-1}(x-1)}$ by L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

My study guide has the following equation:

$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\ln x}{\tanh ^{-1}(x-1)}
$$

And I can follow the process with L'Hospital's rule

$$
=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{2 x-x^{2}}{x}
$$

But I am lost as to why $ 2-x=-\infty$ and not $2$

$$
=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} 2-x=-\infty
$$

**Screenshot below:**

[image]

Comment: What are you talking about? The limit *is* $2$.

Comment: The study guide says neg infinity. Which is why I am lost on this.

Comment: I take it that the study guide is wrong and I am not missing something obvious. Thanks.

Comment: For $x\to 0$ the limit is $2,$ but it looks like instead the limit $x\to+\infty$ has been used at the end. Is it an error in your study guide or have you read it wrong?

Comment: I just added the photo.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noticed in the comments, there is clearly a typo indeed by L'Hospital we would obtain

$$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{\ln x}{\tanh ^{-1}(x-1)}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{\frac1x}{\frac1{2x-x^2}}=2-x =2$$

as an alternative, recall that

$$\tanh ^{-1}(x)=\frac12 \ln (1+x)-\frac12 \ln (1-x) \implies \tanh ^{-1}(x-1)=\frac12 \ln (x)-\frac12 \ln (2-x) $$

and therefore we can directly evaluate the limit as follows

$$\frac{\ln x}{\tanh ^{-1}(x-1)}=\frac{\ln x}{\frac12 \ln (x)-\frac12 \ln (2-x)}=\frac1{\frac12 +\frac{\ln (2-x)}{2\ln x}} \to \frac1{\frac 12 + 0}=2$$

Comment: Thank you for the alternative to evaluate directly.  That really helped clarify.

Comment: You are welcome! When possibile is always better avoid l’Hospital rule as a tool to solve limits. Bye